# How to merge rows/cells in apache hssfsheet?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am writing an application to generate xls sheets in which i need to merge some rows to make the column headers. Though i have been to merge the rows but in doing so the cell data is getting lost. Below is the portion of my code,please help!

```
Region region = new Region();
int firstRow = 1;
int lastRow = 3;
int firstCol = 0;
int lastCol = 6;

region.setColumnFrom((short)firstCol);
region.setColumnTo((short)lastCol);
region.setRowFrom(firstRow); 
region.setRowTo(lastRow);
sheet.addMergedRegion(region);
```

Comment: Which cells are you loosing data from when you do this?

Comment: I am writing data into the cells of the second row and i am trying to merge all the three rows and post the same as column headers . But on applying the above mentioned code,the data is getting disappeared.

Comment: I have a feeling that only the data in the top-left most cell remains after merging. Does that cell's value still show up?

Comment: If i go by your suggestion the data might show up but my requirement isn't that. As i have different column headers i need to write into more than 1 cell.. In this scenario how can the merging be done?

Comment: If you merge the cells, then you can no longer write to them independently! As a handy hint, if you can't do it in Excel, then you'll never be able to do it with POI...